# Adding Jlabel to java applet

Tags: java, applet, jlabel

I used the following code to add a label to a java applet. These lines are inside the paint(Graphics g) method:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(s);
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(icon);
add(myLabel);
```

When I call add(myLabel), the screen is cleared and everything I have drawn before is gone.
Why?

Comment: what is the layout used?

Comment: The layout is freeDesign

Comment: Do I have to use another type of layout?

Comment: @user1077980 I hope that you use JApplet and not Applet because not good idea mixing pre-historic Applet with Swing JComponents

Comment: No :S ... I'm using Applet
I want to create an animation for a number of pictures and I'm tring to do that using Jlabels with icons for that purpose

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - **Don't mix Swing and AWT components**.

Answer (score 4):

> these lines are inside the paint(Graphics g) method:

You should NEVER add a component to a GUI in the paint() method.

Also, if you need to do custom painting, you should be overriding paintComponent() not paint().

I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on:

1. How to Use Labels
2. Performing Custom Painting

that can help you.

There is also a secton on `Using Layout Managers`. I don't know what Free Design it, but I doubt you should be using it.

Comment: *"Also, if you need to do custom painting, you should be overriding paintComponent() not paint()."*  But first the OP must be using a class (i.e. not `Applet` **or** `JApplet`) that *has* a `paintComponent()` method!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) said.

Never add components on the `paint` method. Every time the component is painted, the following code is executed

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(s);
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(icon);
add(myLabel);
```

This way you are 100% sure you will run out of memory at some point as you are adding a new JLabel every time the component is painted. You should add the label when the parent component is created. 
If you want to have animations in your application then I suggest you load these images and put them inside a `List` that you can access from the `paintComponent` method.

```
List<JLabel> images = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
// populate images when the application needs them...
// ...
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
   // get the image your want to draw
   JLabel imageToDraw = images.get(imageIndex);
}
```